# bpy.ops.transform.translate does not work as expected for object just linked from one collection to another

Tags: scripting, transforms

I have a method that iterate through a collection(the assetsHandCollection), copies (link copy) the object to another collection(the gestureCollection) and then it should move the linked object.
This is the method:

```
def make_gestures():
    gestureCollection = bpy.data.collections.get("Gesture")
    for hand in assetsHandCollection.objects:
        linkedCopyHand = hand.copy()
        gestureCollection.objects.link(linkedCopyHand)
        linkedCopyHand.hide_viewport = False
        linkedCopyHand.hide_render = False
        linkedCopyHand.hide_select = False
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = linkedCopyHand
        bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(50, 0, 0), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(True, False, False), mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
```

The object are correctly linked to the new collection but they are not moved.

If I replace the line:

```
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(50, 0, 0), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(True, False, False), mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
```

with

```
linkedCopyHand.matrix_world.translation += Vector((50, 0,0))
```

It works, the oject are correctly linked and translated.

If I check in the console which is the last active object after my script finished to run (with bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active), it is, correctly, one of the object that I have just link copied. If the console I try to run the command:

```
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(50, 0, 0), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(True, False, False), mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
```

It return CANCELLED, without any further detail.

Comment: Would go with the _"It works, the oject are correctly linked and translated."_ part and ditch the op.  Why didn't it work:? My guess without testing is  `ob.select_set(True)` to  select as well as setting to active, since the op prob works only on  selected objects.

Comment: Or that the other collection being linked into doesn't have context.  Anyway to reiterate wouldn't use the op.

Comment: Thanks @batFINGER for your reply. Yes I know, If it works I should not care too much but still I would like to use the methods that the API provides and learn those, instead of patching the matrices directly. Just a question, what do you mean for "other collection being linked into doesn't have context" ? I see the source and destination collections in the outliner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Objects need to be selected.**

Since the operator works on all selected objects and you are translating each the same, could select and call the operator once.  *Tip only need to set non default values in an operator call*

As an example will use default file, and set active object to `None` and assume no other objects selected

```
>>> C.view_layer.objects.active = None
```

Selecting works:

```
>>> for o in D.collections['Collection 1'].objects:
...     o.select_set(True)
...     
>>> bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 0, 1))
{'FINISHED'}
```

Overriding context

```
>>> c = {"selected_objects" : D.collections['Collection 1'].objects}
>>> bpy.ops.transform.translate(c, value=(0, 0, 1))
{'FINISHED'}
```

Putting it together to add a copy of each object in 'Collection 1' to 'foo'.

Copies the objects, links them to foo and moves them using one call of overridden operator.

```
>>> bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
{'FINISHED'}

>>> foo = D.collections.new(name="Foo")
>>> C.scene.collection.children.link(foo)


>>> obs = [o.copy() for o in D.collections['Collection 1'].objects]
>>> for o in obs:
...     foo.objects.link(o)
...     

>>> bpy.ops.transform.translate({"selected_objects" : obs}, value=(0, 0, 1))
{'FINISHED'}
```

**Ditch ops when possible**

> but still I would like to use the methods that the API provides and
>   learn those, instead of patching the matrices directly.

IMO it's the other way around, the operator is basically a bridge between UI and API.  For transforms you are far better off manipulating the matrices directly. There are some ops I would suggest you never use, eg adding a modifier.  Why? see

https://blender.stackexchange.com/question/7358/python-performance-with-blender-operators

Hence you have already found what would have been my suggestion re answering this and manipulate the matrices directly and not rely on operators and a lot of diddling around to get context.

Comment: Thanks @batFINGER for your detailed answer. The most reliable way to move the object, with or without selection, it has been changing directly the matrix_world.translation, as you were suggesting.